# Ball reflection of a wall at an angle not working

Tags: java, math, collision, dot-product

I am trying to make a ball bounce of a wall. The walls can be at any angle and the ball can hit the wall at any angle. The ball has a velocity vector. I have calculated and normalized the normal line of the wall that the ball collides with. This code below is what I use to calculate the dot product:

```
public float dotProduct(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2){
    float theta1 = (float) (Math.atan(v1.getY()/v1.getX()));
    float theta2 = (float) (Math.atan(v2.getY()/v2.getX()));
    float alpha = theta1 - theta2;
    float v1Magnitude = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(v1.getX()), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(v1.getY()), 2));
    float v2Magnitude = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(v2.getX()), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(v2.getY()), 2));
    return (float) Math.abs((v1Magnitude * v2Magnitude * Math.cos(alpha)));
}
```

For some reason the ball just bounces off in some weird direction at a high speed. This is the main function that calculates the reflection velocity:

startX, startY, stopX and stopY are the co-ordinates of the wall.

```
   public Vector2 calculateReflection(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY){
    Vector2 normal;

    normal = new Vector2(-(stopY - startY), (stopX - startX));

    normal = normalize(normal);

    float velocityDotProduct = dotProduct(velocity, normal);
    Vector2 reflectionVelocity = new Vector2(velocity.getX() - 2*velocityDotProduct*normal.getX(), 
                                             velocity.getY() - 2*velocityDotProduct*normal.getY());

    return reflectionVelocity;
}
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you're using the correct equations? You might want to check with [Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/107095) if you're not sure.

Comment: Did you per chance switch the arguments of the constructor when you create `reflectionVelocity` (i.e. shouldn't the first argument be x and the second y)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal vector to a wall from A(ax,ay) to E(ex,ey) should be

```
-(ey - ay), ex - ax

public Vector calculateReflection( Vector velocity){
    double velocityDotProduct = Vector.dotProduct(normal, velocity);
    Vector reflectionVelocity = 
       new Vector(velocity.getX() + 2*velocityDotProduct*normal.getX(),
       velocity.getY() + 2*velocityDotProduct*normal.getY());
    return reflectionVelocity;
}
public void normalize(){
    double d = Math.sqrt( x*x + y*y );
    x /= d;
    y /= d;
}

public static double dotProduct(Vector v1, Vector v2){
    double res = v1.getX()*v2.getX() + v1.getY()*v2.getY();
}

public class Reflect {
private Vector normal;

public Reflect(double begX, double begY, double endX, double endY ){
    normal = new Vector(-(endY - begY), endX - begX);
    normal.normalize();
    System.out.println( "normal: " + normal );
}

public Vector calculateReflection( Vector velocity){
     double velocityDotProduct = Vector.dotProduct(normal, velocity);
     Vector reflectionVelocity = 
       new Vector(velocity.getX() - 2*velocityDotProduct*normal.getX(),
           velocity.getY() - 2*velocityDotProduct*normal.getY());
     return reflectionVelocity;
}
```

Comment: Oh darn, I see. I must have been asleep when coding that lol. Also, what is "b" in that equation you used?

Comment: b like b in bouncing ball.

Comment: The direction of n is not clear since you may swap A and E. I'm not sure how to resolve that except by computing both alternatives and check that |b'| = |b|. (My mechanics lecture is too far away.)

Comment: I changed the normal equation and swapped the X and Y in the reflection velocity. I didnt know how to implement the equation with b into the code though. So far, I have:

Comment: Code doesnt format correctly. How about I make a new question?

Comment: New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725098/ball-reflection-not-working

Comment: Also, the angle is simply the difference: alpha = theta1 - theta2;

Comment: Annoying, but I think I've got all the angles covered.

Comment: Ah, the balls are now bouncing off the walls at the correct angle. It's just that on one of the walls, the ball seems to rebound off at an extremely fast speed. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the dot product calculation or the direction the ball is coming at the wall.

Comment: Perhaps edit the wall + ball vectors into your Q? Also, I did change things considerably from the first try,

Comment: Co-Ordinates of wall which ball rebounds at extreme speed:     Start(620, 900) End(1600, 1000). Velocity of ball at intersection with that wall: (4.6, 42.2)

Comment: (4.6,42.2) reflected (13.028689200329763,-40.401154163231666) both have same abs, so should be OK.

Comment: I just noticed in your code you did your dot product differently to mine so I changed it and it now works. Thank you :D